# Why I am getting duplicate records for the following SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    l.ModelTypeIndexNumber AS [Model Index Number],
    l.TestGroupname AS [Test Group],
    lf.CE_Fuel AS [Fuel],
    CASE 
        WHEN lf.Electricity = '' THEN '(missing)' \
        ELSE  lf.Electricity 
    END AS [Electric Motor Energy Source],
    tg.TG_Fuel + ', EL' AS [TG Fuel Sources],
    CASE 
        WHEN l.LabelCalculationApproachIdentifier ='PHEV' THEN  'PHEV'
        ELSE '(Not PHEV)' 
    END AS [Label Calculation Approach] 
FROM Relational.Label l 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        lbl.SubmissionId, 
        lbl.ModelTypeIndexNumber, 
        COUNT(*) AS lblFuelCount, 
        MAX(CASE 
                WHEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier <>'EL' THEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier 
                ELSE NULL 
            END) AS CE_Fuel, 
        MAX(CASE 
                WHEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier ='EL' THEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier 
                ELSE '' 
            END) AS Electricity 
    FROM Relational.Label lbl 
    INNER JOIN Relational.FuelUsage fu 
        ON lbl.LabelId=fu.LabelId 
    WHERE lbl.SubmissionId=@SubmissionId 
    GROUP BY lbl.SubmissionId, lbl.ModelTypeIndexNumber 
    ) AS lf 
    ON l.SubmissionId=lf.SubmissionId 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        rtg.SubmissionId, 
        rtg.TestGroupName, 
        MAX(CASE 
            WHEN ds.FuelId <> 'EL' THEN ds.FuelId 
            ELSE NULL 
        END) AS TG_Fuel 
    FROM Relational.DriveSource ds 
    INNER JOIN Relational.TestGroup rtg 
        ON ds.TestGroupId=rtg.TestGroupId 
    WHERE rtg.SubmissionId=@SubmissionId 
    GROUP BY rtg.SubmissionId, rtg.TestGroupName 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND MAX(CASE WHEN ds.FuelId ='EL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    ) AS tg 
    ON lf.SubmissionId=tg.SubmissionId 
    AND l.TestGroupName = tg.TestGroupName 
WHERE (lf.Electricity = '' AND l.LabelCalculationApproachIdentifier = 'PHEV')
```

It is generating the following output:

```
Model Index Number    Test Group    Fuel    TG Fuel Source(s)    Label Calculation Approach   
19                    ABC.1987      GP      DX, EL               PHEV
19                    XYZ.1989      DM      DS, EL               PHEV
20                    ABC.1987      GP      DX. EL               PHEV
20                    XYZ.1989      DM      DS, EL               PHEV
```

BUT I AM EXPECTING THE FOLLOWING RESULT:

```
Model Index Number    Test Group    Fuel    TG Fuel Source(s)    Label Calculation Approach
19                    ABC.1987      GP      DX, EL               PHEV
20                    XYZ.1989      DM      DS, EL               PHEV
```

I do not want duplication. Perhaps joining issue. I tried by DISTINCT. What am I doing wrong in my query?

Answer (score 0):

> Why I am getting duplicate records ?

The answer to this question depends very much on the data in the source tables.

---

This is just a guess (as I don't have your real tables and data I cannot run the query):

I think you need a `GROUP BY` statement at the end of the query as well. Your query could look like this:

```
SELECT 
    l.ModelTypeIndexNumber AS [Model Index Number],
    l.TestGroupname AS [Test Group],
    MAX(lf.CE_Fuel AS [Fuel]),
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN lf.Electricity = '' THEN '(missing)' \
        ELSE  lf.Electricity 
    END) AS [Electric Motor Energy Source],
    MAX(tg.TG_Fuel + ', EL') AS [TG Fuel Sources],
    MAX(CASE 
        WHEN l.LabelCalculationApproachIdentifier ='PHEV' THEN  'PHEV'
        ELSE '(Not PHEV)' 
    END) AS [Label Calculation Approach] 
FROM Relational.Label l 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        lbl.SubmissionId, 
        lbl.ModelTypeIndexNumber, 
        COUNT(*) AS lblFuelCount, 
        MAX(CASE 
                WHEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier <>'EL' THEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier 
                ELSE NULL 
            END) AS CE_Fuel, 
        MAX(CASE 
                WHEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier ='EL' THEN fu.FuelUsageIdentifier 
                ELSE '' 
            END) AS Electricity 
    FROM Relational.Label lbl 
    INNER JOIN Relational.FuelUsage fu 
        ON lbl.LabelId=fu.LabelId 
    WHERE lbl.SubmissionId=@SubmissionId 
    GROUP BY lbl.SubmissionId, lbl.ModelTypeIndexNumber 
    ) AS lf 
    ON l.SubmissionId=lf.SubmissionId 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        rtg.SubmissionId, 
        rtg.TestGroupName, 
        MAX(CASE 
            WHEN ds.FuelId <> 'EL' THEN ds.FuelId 
            ELSE NULL 
        END) AS TG_Fuel 
    FROM Relational.DriveSource ds 
    INNER JOIN Relational.TestGroup rtg 
        ON ds.TestGroupId=rtg.TestGroupId 
    WHERE rtg.SubmissionId=@SubmissionId 
    GROUP BY rtg.SubmissionId, rtg.TestGroupName 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND MAX(CASE WHEN ds.FuelId ='EL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    ) AS tg 
    ON lf.SubmissionId=tg.SubmissionId 
    AND l.TestGroupName = tg.TestGroupName 
WHERE (lf.Electricity = '' AND l.LabelCalculationApproachIdentifier = 'PHEV') 
GROUP BY     
    l.ModelTypeIndexNumber,
    l.TestGroupname
```